# Ubuntu Gnome LTS 16.04. Laptop's wifi keeps cutting out and it won't scan for networks

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Randomly, my wifi goes out and all networks disappear from the list. Refreshing does nothing, it won't scan. I have to go to Connect To Hidden Network in settings and manually type in my SSID and password again. Then it connects and the other networks show up again. If it helps, I checked install 3rd party MP3 and wifi software during installation

```
price@OlReliableJr:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8211]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

The installation of that custom driver failed. The output of network diagnostics is here. http://pastebin.com/P5PaXd7h

Comment: Hi. It may be worth including your wifi driver details in the question which can be found using `sudo lshw -C network` from terminal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's in there now, sorry for the wait.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. It provides further information about the status of your wireless network adapter like signal strength et cetera.